# How can I put a button on the same line as the input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I have i a problem, i wanted to put the button "eye" on the same line as my input.

What I have done :

```
<body style="padding: 100px;">
    <h1>Connexion</h1>
    <div class="form d-flex justify-content-center bg-light pb-5 border">
        <div class="col-4"> 
            <form method="POST" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><b>Email: </b></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Entrer l'email" name="email" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Merci de saisir une adresse mail.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label><b>Mot de passe: </b></label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Entrer le mot de passe" name="password" required>
                    <button type="button" id="eye"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Merci de saisir un mot de passe.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value='Se connecter'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image: Text]

As you can see my button is under my input and I dont know why...

Thanks

Comment: Float. Inline-block. For example.

Comment: Please create a [mre] that includes your CSS. Use the `<>` button.

Comment: all my code is in html. Already tried with Float and Inline-block

Comment: You're using **bootstrap**... here's how to do this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/input-group/#button-addons your form, fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/bqxj8uf3/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place your input and button into a div container and use flex style to make them appear on the same row.

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Entrer le mot de passe" name="password" required>
    <button type="button" id="eye"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}
```

This should make your input and button show up on the same row.

Comment: Your welcome! :) Be sure to mark it as the answer if it worked out for you.

Comment: But this part :  <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Merci de saisir un mot de passe.
                    </div> is no longer displayed

Comment: Sorry but I had to downvote this; OP is using bootstrap and needs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/input-group/#button-addons

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything you intend to put on a single line in a single div in the html like:

```
<div class="form-line">
    <div class="input">
        <label><b>Mot de passe: </b></label>
        <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Entrer le mot de passe" name="password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="eye"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
</div>
```

(I placed label and input in their own div to retain whatever stacking styling you have on there when we add css next).
Then in the css you can just give it either a a flex or an inline on contents rule.

```
.form-line{
    display: flex;
}
```

or...

```
.form-line *{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I had to downvote this; OP is using bootstrap and needs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/input-group/#button-addons